# Exporting geometry form Sentinel 1 data using -S1 TOPS SPLIT Analyzer (STSA)

Tags: python, sentinelsat

Im looking to export geometry from Sentinel 1 SLC product.
Im using S1 TOPS SPLIT Analyzer (STSA) which is documented [here](https://github.com/pbrotoisworo/s1-tops-split-analyzer).

Everything seems to work up to the export part.
My code as per example in documentation:

```
import stsa

s1 = stsa.TopsSplitAnalyzer(target_subswaths=['iw1', 'iw2', 'iw3'], polarization='vh')

# METHOD 2: Load using Copernicus Scihub API
s1.load_api(
    'myusername',
    'S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20210627T043102_20210627T043130_038521_048BB9_DA44',
    'mypassword'
)
```

But when I try to export geometry either shapfile, geojson or csv with:

```
s1.to_json('json_output.json')
```

I get an error:
[image]

I would love to know how to solve this issue.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Ill share my findings.
I believe the error is related to shapely version.
I have updated my shapely to 1.8.1.post1 and everything seem to work fine.
Related [post](https://forum.step.esa.int/t/python-s1-tops-split-analyzer/29047/13) from SNAP Forum.

If anyone have better explanation, please feel free to share.